# Has anyone got experience with Open PHP/HTML/JS In Browser for Visual Code?

Tags: php, browser, plugins

I just installed v 1.08. Every time I try to run it I get this error message:

> "Unable to launch selected browser (Custom). Error: Command failed:
>   C:\Program\Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe
>   "http:\localhost:8888\\flut.php}" The system cannot find the path
>   specified. The system cannot find the path specified."

In the settings I entered:
Custom browser path:

> C:\Program\Files (x86)\AVG\Browser\Application\AVGBrowser.exe

Custom URL to open:

> http:\:8888\${relativeDirnameDocumentRoot}\${fileBasename}}

Document root folder:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\

I have made all sorts of changes to the slashes combinations, nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps that worked for me:

1. `Open Folder` (instead of `Open File`) in which your php files are stored.
2. Track `Preferences` (or [gear wheel icon]) > `Settings` and choose `Workspace` tab just below the `Search Settings` input box.
3. Expand `Extensions` on the left and find `Open PHP/HTML/JS in browser`.
4. Set the desired port number to both of `Custom Host` and `Custom Url To Open` in suggested ways there.
5. You'll find `.vscode` folder is automatically created in the folder you initially opened. In there `settings.json` file is stored as you set.
6. Run `Open PHP/HTML/JS in browser`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your configuration this way:

**Open-PHP-HTML-JS-in-browser: Custom Url To Open**
http://localhost:80/${relativeDirnameDocumentRoot}/${fileBasename}

**Open-PHP-HTML-JS-in-browser: Document Root Folder**
C:/xampp/htdocs/

It works for me as I have Apache running in 80 port.